# -ly adverb placement: "primarily consisted of [noun]" or "consisted primarily of [noun]"

Tags: adverb-position

I'm troubled by "primarily consisted of" versus "consisted primarily of."

To me, the former seems clumsy, and the latter seems smoother.

I'm American and live in the mid-west. Is the second construct more pleasing to me because of where I live (a regional "thing"), or is it actually the correct one?

Comment: It's an option, and many native speakers take it. Adverbs can go in a lot of places. Why you prefer it is likely your own personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

There technically is not a *correct* one, as both options are grammatically correct. The choice is simply up to the author or speaker.